# How to transform/translate a coordinate system from upside down to right way up using vvvv SVG-Lib for C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, svg, coordinates, vvvv

It's a famous Problem, that programmatically generated SVG code is/will be displayed upside down:
[image: SVG is upside down]
(if you compare the value of the numbers to the polyline's incline or rise, you see it's upside down)

I'm working with a non-documentated library: [vvvv SVG](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG).
Does someone know, how to make the SVG Display right way up?
Something similay to d3.js's way:

```
data.sort(function compareNumbers(a, b) {
    return a - b;
})
```

Or do I have to manage that with some mathematics?

(I hope, it's clear what I like to knwo/ask :))